# Is there a way to select all elements with a certain property value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-1.6

I'm building a fairly simple plugin with jQuery that validates a form. When an element is assessed to be valid I run

```
$(this).prop("valid", false);
```

In certain instances I'm going to want to block the form from submitting if anything is invalid. Essentially I'm looking for a way to select all the elements where the valid property is false? Am I going to have to iterate over all relevant elements and check for a false reading or is there a jQuery selector that I've overlooked? Something like:

```
$("input[valid=false]");
```

Would be nice. Any suggestions?

Comment: keep in mind that 1.6 treats properties and attributes very differently. Properties are defined on first load. So instead of using `prop` you should use `attr` if you want to change values. Your selector is correct. Just quote the `false` bit

Comment: @JohnP Is jQuery clever enough to work with `false` instead of `"false"` there? Maybe I stuffed something up, but it [didn't work for me](http://jsfiddle.net/QQsvJ/).

Comment: @alex haha well we'd expect it to. But I've answered a couple of questions where adding the quotes fixed the issue. Better safe than sorry!

Comment: @JohnP Check out the fiddle... did I do something wrong?

Comment: @alex I'm guessing that that the `[attr='value']` filter does not pick up properties. 1.6 has drawn the line between properties and attributes. When I changed the code to use `attr()`, calling `.attr("a", true)` translates to `[a="a"]`. So looks like booleans are out ^_^

Comment: Reading it again, my first comment is completely the other way around >.<

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this...

```
$('input').filter(function() {
   return this.valid === false; 
});
```

It will return all `input` elements (do you mean `:input`?) where its `valid` property *is* `false` (notice strict equality comparison).

Comment: Sorry I actually tried to but I had to wait a few minutes and then got waylaid. Thanks again for the answer

Answer (score 5):

### Reusable `:invalid` jQuery selector filter

You could write a simple selector filter:

```
$.extend($.exp[":"], {
    invalid: function(element) {
        return element.valid === false;
    }
});
```

Then simply combine it with whatever selector your using to get your elements ie:

```
// all invalid inputs
$(":input:invalid");
// or all invalid text boxes
$("input[type=text]:invalid");
```

That's it.

Let's put it all in a simple plugin that you can easily include in your script code or put in a script file (for reusability purposes on several pages as well as several applications if you'd use the same validation functionality):

```
(function($) {

    $.extend($.exp[":"], {
        invalid: function(element) {
            return element.valid === false;
        }
    });

})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0):

use this:

```
$(':input').each( function() {
   return $(this).prop('valid');
});
```